# Disable Microsoft Autofill/Authenticator for specific input fields?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to disable the autofill functionality provided by the [Microsoft Autofill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/microsoft-autofill/fiedbfgcleddlbcmgdigjgdfcggjcion?hl=en) browser extension for a specific input field?

For example, we have an app and lets say you're creating a category. This has a field called "name" and it keeps popping up the autofill popup for user's with the extension installed. This is suggesting peoples names that they've used in their browser. This is obviously incorrect and the users are getting annoyed with it. Is there something we can do to stop it showing on a field when we know it would never be relevant?

Is there anywhere to see/provide feedback for the autofill extension and get a response?